# Problems with utf-8 encoding in php

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

Another utf-8 related problem I believe...

I am using php to update data in a mysql db then display that data elsewhere in the site.  Previously I have run into utf-8 problems before where special characters are displayed as question marks when viewed in a browser but this one seems slightly different.

I have a number of records to enter that contain the è character.  If I enter this directly in the db then it appears correctly on the page so I take this to mean that utf-8 content is being output correctly.

However when I try and update the values in the db through php, then the è character is replaced.  What appears instead is & Atilde ; & uml ; (without the spaces) which appears in the browser as Ã¨

I have the tables in the database set to use UTF-8.  I believe this is correct cos, as mentioned, if I update the db through phpMyAdmin, its all ok.  Similarly I have set the character encoding for the page which seems to be correct.  I am also running the sql statement "SET NAMES 'utf8';" before trying to update the db.

Anyone have any other ideas as to where the problem may lie?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup.

The character you have is [LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH GRAVE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00e8/index.htm).  As you can see, in UTF-8 that character is encoded into two bytes `0xC3` and `0xA8`.

But in many default, western encodings (such as ISO-8859-1) which are single-byte only, this multi-byte character is decoded as two separate characters, [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH TILDE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00c3/index.htm) and [DIAERESIS](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a8/index.htm).  Notice how they are both encoded as [C3](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00c3/charset_support.htm) and [A8](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a8/charset_support.htm) in ISO-8859-1?

Furthermore, it looks like PHP is processing these characters through [htmlentities()](https://www.php.net/htmlentities) which result in the `&Atilde;` and `&uml;` respectively.

So, where exactly is the problem in your code?  Well, `htmlentities()` could be doing it all by itself since its 3rd argument is a encoding name - which you may not have properly set to `'UTF-8'`. But it could be some other string processing function as well. *(Note: As a general rule, it's a bad idea to store HTML entities in the database - this step should be reserved for time of display)*

There are a bunch of other ways to trip yourself up with UTF-8 in php - I suggest hitting up [the cheatsheet](http://developer.loftdigital.com/blog/php-utf-8-cheatsheet) and make sure you're in good shape.

Comment: Yup. A bit lengthy way to say "get rid of htmlentities".

Comment: I always like to explain exactly what's going on when encodings are involved.  Anything I can do to elevate understanding is a win in my book.

Comment: Cheers for that. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Well it is your own code convert characters into entities.
To make it right:

1. Ban `htmlentities` function from your scripts forever.
2. Use `htmlspecialchars`, but not on insert, but whan displaying data.
3. Repair existing data in the database using `html_entity_decode`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're taking the results of some form submission and inserting the results in the database. If so, you must ensure that you instruct the browser to send UTF-8 data and you should validate the user input for a valid UTF-8 stream.

Change your form element to include accept-charset:

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" ... >
    <input type="text name="field" />
    ...
</form>
```

Validate the data with:

```
$valid = array_key_exists("field", $_POST) && !is_array($_POST['field']) &&
    preg_match('//u', $_POST['field']) && ...; //check length with mb_strlen etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss Content-Type declaration on the html page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

If you don't have it, the browser will guess the encoding, and convert any characters outside of that encoding to entities when posting a form.